# Traversing simplexml_load_file and sending each element node through cURL

Tags: php, xml, curl

In my test.xml file I have multiple `Field` nodes like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<Fields>
  <Field>
    <ID>01258</ID>
    <Name>abc</Name>
    <Contact>Contact One</Contact>
  </Field>
  <Field>
    <ID>52458</ID>
    <Name>def</Name>
    <Contact>Contact Two</Contact>
  </Field>
  <Field>
    <ID>74287</ID>
    <Name>xyz</Name>
    <Contact>Contact Three</Contact>
  </Field>
</Fields>
```

I would like to send each `Field` node one at a time through cURL to an API. This is what I have done in my PHP:

```
<?php
$inputFilename = 'test.xml';
$url = 'http://api-url......' // API URL

$xml = simplexml_load_file($inputFilename);
foreach($xml->Field as $field) {
  $input_xml = '<Field>'.$field.'</Field>';

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $input_xml);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
}
```

Now I have a problem. `$input_xml` does not seem to hold the correct xml. When I run this code, I get this error:

```
XML Parsing Error: junk after document element
.....
Line Number 10, Column 8:   
        </Field><Field>
  --------------^
```

How do I fix this? How do I make sure `$field` is actually outputting an xml?

Comment: Check what $field is by using var_dump. You may have to cast it as a string like ```$field = (string)$field;```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use DOMXPath which can correctly find all your field

```
$doc = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
$doc->loadXML(file_get_contents($inputFilename));

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$field = $xpath->query("/fields/field");
foreach ($fields as $field)
  {
     $field->ownerDocument;
  }
```

You even don't use simplexml_load_file and `$input_xml = '<Field>'.$field.'</Field>';`